# Web application with protege backend

Tags: php, ontology, protege

I have an ontology built in protege 5+ based on the database https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Soybean+(Large) . I have created the database in H2 db and mapped the data to my ontology using Ontop Mapping. Now I want to develop a web based application using php and the ontology I developed as the backend. I have looked upon how to connect protege with php but haven't come up with any successful result. 
Is it possible to develop a web application with php and a protege backend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, there is no PHP API for accessing Protege.

The longer answer is:

Protege comes in 2 flavours, namely desktop and web-based. Both are written in Java. Neither can be used as a backend. Rather, Protege will store ontologies in files on the file system. You can use the OWL API to load and browse an ontology stored in a file.

You can find the latest version (version 5.x) of the OWL API at  https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi.

For an example of how to load an ontology from a file you can look at the example provided as part of version 4.x of the OWL API (see https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java).